# Script Errors on First File Download

Tags: powershell

Our script works, but on the first file download it downloads the TMP file, and doesn't convert to the actual filename. This only occurs on the first file. I have a feeling it has to do with `$ImageFix`. It didn't occur prior to that addition.

Comment: Stop using variables before you assigned a value to them. I already told you that in my answer to your previous question where you made the same mistake.

Comment: You are very correct!

Answer (score 1):

And it renames all the files with the name of the *previous* image.

You need to calculate `$ImageFix` after getting `$Image`, it doesn't make sense to do it before.

```
foreach ($line in $content)
{
    $tmp = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $wc.DownloadFile($line, $tmp)

    $Image = if ($wc.ResponseHeaders['Content-Disposition']) {
        $wc.ResponseHeaders['Content-Disposition'] -replace '^.*?filename=', ''
    } else {
        ($line -split '/')[-1] -replace '[?*"\\]', '_'
    }

    $ImageFix = [uri]::UnescapeDataString($Image)

    Move-Item $tmp (Join-Path $Loc $ImageFix)

    LogWrite "$line,$ImageFix"
}
```